# Berkeley DB JE JDB files keep increasing

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

I am debugging a disk space issue in my system and found that .jdb files are consuming most of the space.

while browsing, found this link https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a14630082, In my case lnSizeCorrectionFactor was around 1.4 and fileDeleted=false.
I ran the disk space command to find the space utilization, it turned out to be non-zero for all the jdb files but most of the files have utilization as single digit values ranging from 2-9.

I am using je-5.0.58 version, which is not latest. My question is according to BDB doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/GettingStartedGuide/backgroundthreads.html#cleaner, jdb file needs to be cleaned if it reaches lesser than default value of 50%. In my case even they are at single digit, why they are not getting  cleaned?

I didn't explicitly set any environment config so it should be using default values by definition. Below is the code to create a bdb repository.

```
 private static Repository createBDBRepository(File environmentHome) throws 
 RepositoryException {
            BDBRepositoryBuilder builder = new BDBRepositoryBuilder();
            builder.setName("localbdb");
            builder.setEnvironmentHomeFile(environmentHome);
            builder.setTransactionNoSync(false);

            // Set BDB-JE flavor
            builder.setProduct("JE");

            builder.setCacheSize(20 * 1024 * 1024L);
            return builder.build();
    }
```

Log line from je.info file

```
   Chose lowest utilized file for cleaning. fileChosen: 0x50cbecc totalUtilization: 49 bestFileUtilization: 8 lnSizeCorrectionFactor: 1.1012049 isProbe: false
   No file selected for cleaning. totalUtilization: 50 bestFileUtilization: 8 lnSizeCorrectionFactor: 1.1012049 isProbe: false
```

Answer (score 1):

As the ForgeRock document describes, this is due to a bug in the version 5 of BDB JE, which has been resolved with version 6 and higher.

Quoting BDB JE 6.x release notes:

> An improvement was made to the calculation of log utilization to avoid
>   under-cleaning or over-cleaning. For example, when log utilization was
>   estimated to be lower than actual utilization, unnecessary
>   over-cleaning would occur, which could reduce performance. Or when log
>   utilization was estimated to be higher than actual utilization,
>   under-cleaning would prevent reclaiming unused disk space. To prevent
>   these problems, the size of each logged record is now stored in the
>   Btree BINs (bottom internal nodes), so that utilization can be
>   calculated correctly during record updates and deletions, while still
>   avoiding a fetch of the old version of the record. With this change,
>   the utilization adjustment facility in the log cleaner, which
>   attempted to compensate for this problem by estimating utilization, is
>   no longer needed by most applications.
>
> Therefore the EnvironmentConfig.CLEANER_ADJUST_UTILIZATION parameter
>   is now false by default rather than true, and will be disabled
>   completely in a future version of JE. For more information, see the
>   javadoc for this parameter.
>
> [#22275] (6.0.7)